# Android HorizontalListView select center item during scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I've implemented my custom HorizontalListView like [This](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Now during scroll of the list I need to always select the central item. 
Does anyone have any idea to implement this?

I tried to implement my OnTouchListener to try to manually select an item in the list, but this is never called, and I do not understand why. This is the code of my OnTouchListener method

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```